# PHP can't read files containing PHP code as text files

Tags: php, security, permissions, fopen

I've stumbled upon the following pecularity:

$handle = fopen(realpath("../folder/files.php"), "r");

can't read a file, but as soon as I remove php tags from the file,
it becomes readable and my scripts prints non-empty file content on the page.
Also, file.php is never ever executed, so I wonder why it is the problem.

I guess somehow Apache or PHP doesn't let read files containing php tags PHP as just text.

How can I enable it for my particular file (course doing it globally would be unsecure)?

Using PHP 5.2.x and Apache 2.0

Comment: Interesting... I also just noticed that. It seems that any file that starts with <something will not be read.

Comment: are you getting an error on the fopen() or during the reading part?  if on the read, what code are you using to read the file?

Comment: Any code is the problem, I used fopen, but file_get_contents causes the same behavior.

Comment: Actually I was wrong on that first comment. It only happens when there is a <? tag. Here's a more relevant test. When using fgets on a file containing this string: "testing <? testing2 ?> testing3", the output is: "testing testing3". It seems php filters out content inside <?, ?> tags.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got it. I was using Google chrome to debug the page, and I realized that when viewing the source, Chrome hides PHP tags for some reason. I ran the same test on Firefox, and viewing the source proved that everything was okay.

Here are the test details:

Code:

```
$fh = fopen("test.php","r");
while ($line = fgets($fh)){
echo $line;
}
```

File to be read (test.php):

```
testing <?php testing2 ?> testing3
```

Rendering (on both Chrome and firefox):

```
testing  testing3
```

View source (using firefox):

```
testing <?php testing2 ?> testing3
```

View source (using Chrome - source of my mistake):

```
testing  testing3
```

Comment: You really got it. That was the case!

Comment: That's a pile of lame. Firefox used to do something similar, where it would  alter the source of the document when you viewed sourse.  (basically showing you the "this is how I interpret that invalid HTML) Because of that I started using curl to debug HTML output.

Comment: Right. Thanks for the insight, Alan. With curl, things most probably can't go wrong.

Comment: ALso to make sure that doesn't happen in the future you could do something like: echo htmlspecialchars($line); or echo str_replace('<?php', '<?php', str_replace('?>', '?>', $line));

Answer (score 7):

Are you sure you're interpreting the output correctly? If you print the file contents directly to your page output, a browser won't display text inside angle brackets because it thinks it's a tag. Serve your content as `text/plain`, or use your browser's "view source" command to make sure you're looking at what's really there, and not just what the browser chose to display.

Comment: I agree. I am able to print everything except the the tags inside <> . But one of test page displays button which is in the php file being read.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm file_get_contents() is working for me. Is it issue only for fopen?

Edit: what error do you get exactly?

Comment: Unlikely, I've just tested - file_get_contents() has the same problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Wadih M. solved the issue. PHP tags hides the whole tag-enclosed php source output in the browser, but View Source shows them. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome PHP thinker. Simply set the reply as a solution (big green check sign) to close the question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am using `htmlspecialchars($line);`

It solved the problem.

Answer (score -1):

rename the file
read it 
get your data
change them
rerename your file :)