# Why would you want trailing spaces in an HTML document?

Tags: html, spaces

I've been looking at the source of the [A List Apart](http://www.alistapart.com) website, and I've noticed something strange - every line (blank or not) has a trailing space. I work in typesetting, so trailing spaces are something I regularly remove out of course, so why in this case would you want them? I have a lot of respect for ALA so I'm assuming there's a good reason!

Comment: I don't see these trailing spaces. I assume you are going to the ALA site and going "View source"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

:P It's not the page, it's Chrome's view source function - it adds a space to each line. Still don't know why though!

Comment: Chrome apparently massages the data. We've seen this here before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/654688/php-cant-read-files-containing-php-code-as-text-files

Answer (score 0):

The html source does not have extra spaces. Used wget to retrieve the page and vim to view.